# A/B Split Test For Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ab-testing

We manage our websites with Wordpress. Recently, we started searching for split test plugins and tools but couldn't find something that supports the following requirements:

1. Test the same post with changes in the Single Post (single.php) file
2. Test changes in stylesheet (stylesheet.css)
3. Test changes in themes

I would appreciate any assistant if anyone is aware of existing tools that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find any solution online so we built one.
In order to make it work, I duplicated the active theme, made the changes in the duplicated theme and created a plugin that dynamically load the themes randomly - 50% the original theme and 50% the duplicated.

The plugin code is as follow:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Theme Split Test
Plugin URI: 
Description: Theme Split Test
Author: Tal Yaari
Author URI: 
Version: 1.0
*/

add_filter('template', 'load_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'load_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'load_theme');
function load_theme($theme) {

    $rand = intval(date('s'));
    if ($rand%2 == 0)
    {
        $theme = 'devoe';
    }
    else
    {
        $theme = 'devoe1';
    }

    return $theme;
}
?>
```